# How can I create a button for each element of a class?

Tags: javascript, class, element

*I'm trying to make it so that every element with the class "author-caro" is appended an individual button. I want the button to redirect people to the author's profile. Yet I have only been able to append one button to the last element. I got a script for styling multiple divs, but apparently styling and appending work differently, so every element gets a style change but only one element gets a button appended. What can I do to append a button to every single element with a class?
*

```js
function onLoader() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("author-caro");
    var i;
    var para = document.createElement("button");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].appendChild(para);
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    }
}
```

```css
.flex {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoader()">

<div class="flex">
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
</div>
```

Comment: move the createElement line inside of the loop. When it is outside it is one element and one element can not live in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

An element can only live in one place so when you append it to another place it moves. So you need to create one button for each place.

```js
function onLoader() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("author-caro");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var para = document.createElement("button");
    x[i].appendChild(para);
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  }
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoader()">

  <div class="flex">
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
  </div>
```

Other option is to clone it

```js
function onLoader() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("author-caro");
  var i;
  var para = document.createElement("button");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].appendChild(para.cloneNode());
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  }
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoader()">

  <div class="flex">
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
    <a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks too old. I think you should consider searching for an up-to-date source to learn.

Secondly, why do you want to add a button inside an anchor tag?
If you need to send visitors to another page, you need anchor, not button. Otherwise you  need a button but not `<a>`. I don't understand your approach. That bweing said, if you want to add:

```
const onloader () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".author-caro").forEach(x => {
    x.appendChild(document.createElement("BUTTON"))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Im using w3 schools, is that outdated?

Comment: Almost always :)

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: For tutorials, Youtube because you can see which is new which is old. And developer.mozilla which is always up-to-date but not for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onLoader() {
    const x = document.getElementsByClassName("author-caro");
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      const para = document.createElement("button");
      x[i].appendChild(para);
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    }
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoader()">

<div class="flex">
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
<a class="author-caro">Yes</a>
<a class="author-robby">Yes</a>
</div>
```

You have to create new button for every iterations(for every elements).
Updated the snippet to resolve your issue!

Also, just a suggestion, use `const` instead of `var` for variable that will never be reassigned and `let` if it is reassigned. More about `let` and `const` [var v/s let v/s const](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to put a button inside elements that have "author-caro" class name .. So you only need to iterate the 'createElement' (put it in the loop) :

```
function onLoader() {
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("author-caro");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  let para = document.createElement("button");
   para.textContent = "click";
    x[i].appendChild(para);
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}}
```